# Augment Angular typescript definitions

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, type-declaration

I am trying to create a TS definition file for https://github.com/niqdev/angular-q-extras

You can find here the full definition I wrote https://github.com/mistic100/DefinitelyTyped/blob/angular-q-extras/types/angular-q-extras/index.d.ts

It only consists of a few methods added to the IQService,
Extract :

```
declare var _: string;
export = _;

import * as angular from 'angular';

declare module 'angular' {
    namespace angular {

        interface IQService {
            allSettled(promises): IPromise<any>;
        }  

    }
}
```

It is heavily based on other definitions of Angular plugins.

The problem is I get the following error when I run the DefinitelyTyped linter or I try to use the definition:

> Cannot augment module 'angular' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.

And also a bunch of:

> Cannot find name 'IPromise'.

I really don't understand why it is working for other definitions and not for mine. I probably forgot one obvious thing but cannot figure out which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re:

> `Cannot augment module 'angular' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.`

Since the Angular type definition says:

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
export = angular;
```

you can't define any more items of the form `angular.foo.bar` that exist at runtime, such as your enum `qextras.PromiseState`, because they would conflict with the `angular` declared variable.  In fact, AFAICT, `qextras.PromiseState` and its constants are not actually defined at runtime under this name by angular-q-extras (maybe they are under another name?  I don't understand how all this Angular stuff works), so it would be misleading to declare them in this way.  One thing you can do is declare only a type instead of the enum:

```
type PromiseState = 'fulfilled' | 'rejected';
```

You might think you'd be able to use a `const enum` because it is compiled out by TypeScript, but I guess there's still a concern that an expression might be ambiguous between the `const enum` and members of the `angular` variable at compile time.  (Edit: [confirmed by the TypeScript team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17372#issuecomment-317578008).)

It looks like the `IPromise` errors are fallout from the `declare module 'angular'` failing to go through.

You didn't ask about this in the question, but it looks to me that you'll also need to remove the `namespace angular` from around `IQService`.  AIUI, even though the Angular type declaration has a `namespace angular`, your augmentation is rooted at what the Angular type declaration specifies as the export, which is the `namespace angular`, so you shouldn't nest another `namespace angular`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed the enum which compiles to actual JS in constrast to the union type. And I had to remove the namespace too.